# Is the CodeIgniter's session class specific to a user's IP address?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, cookies, ip

Basically my clients found a bug on my server where I have multiple CodeIgniter projects hosted. For all the projects, I use the same CodeIgniter session variables for certain parts of the program, like login/membership. My clients, who are completely in different locations, different IP addresses, were running into issues which caused me to believe it's because of the CodeIgniter's session variable names conflicting among the projects.

So, if the users are in different locations, different IP addresses, shouldn't CodeIgniter's session class take care of that? Or do I have setup/configure to do that?

Comment: *" My clients, who are completely in different locations, different ips, where running into issues which caused me to believe its because of the codeigniter's session variable names conflicting among the projects."* what issues? i don't believe your interpritation of the cause is going to be correct.

Comment: Are you using file-based sessions?  If so, are you using different file directories for each application?

Comment: By default codeigniter ignores IP addresses but I don't see how IP's are relevant to the issue you explained. The only time you'd want to enable codeigniter's understanding of IPs is for security reasons (so users can't switch computers but use the same session identifier). If there are two different users in two different locations, no matter their credentials they'll use two different session identifiers.

Comment: What, exactly, are some of the issues you're experiencing? Please be as detailed as possible.

Comment: how come my previous comment didn't post...

Comment: If a bug comes up, and you have to ask yourself if it lies in your code or in a widely-distributed library - 99% of the time, it's in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CodeIgniter makes dedicated session IDs, with the user's IP address as one of the components. The chance of a duplicate session ID is very slim, to say the least.

More information: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

You could try to add user data to the session ID to further decrease the possibility of duplicate IDs, but I doubt the problem is in the CodeIgniter class though.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match user's IP address, you can specify it in your `./application/config/config.php`:

```
$config['sess_match_ip'] = TRUE;
```

Comment: I don't think this is what he was asking. That's a security related flag.